# Contar cuantas parejas hay en un un vector de numeros

Tags: array

Tengo una duda en mi codigo, quiero que me cuente las parejas de numeros, el problema es que me cuenta el numero que se parece a la pareja por ejemplo:  2-2-2-1 me cuenta 3 y me deberia contar solo uno
adjunto mi codigo

```
 //#include<iostream>
//using namespace std;

//int main (){

//int n,contador =0,j =0;
//cin>>n;
//int arreglo[n] = {0};

 //for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

//cin>>arreglo[i];
 // cout<<arreglo[i]<<endl;

if (i != 0) {
for(int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
if (arreglo[i] == arreglo[z]) {

contador++;

   }
}
    }
}
 cout<<contador <<" " ;


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! supongo que esto es c++??? aclara el lenguaje. Igual aca hay un problema de logica, vos estas sumando por cada vez que un numero se repite.. y eso pasa varias veces.. no estas sumando una sola vez... si quisieras sumar una sola vez... que tendrias que hacer?

Comment: Utilizar un if ?

Comment: Podria ser.. como? aprende a hacer debug.. escribi tu algoritmo en tu papel.. comenta tu codigo.. que hace tu codigo?

Comment: MI codigo cuenta los numeros que se repiten mas no las parejas, lo cual es lo que no quiero

Comment: Y como contarias parejas?

Comment: Perdon es contar los que no tienen pareja

Comment: queria hacerle asi

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    cin>>arreglo[i];

    for(int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
    if (arreglo[i] == arreglo[z]) {
            contador++;

    }
    }
}
cout<<contador ;

Comment: eso que mostras es lo mismo de arriba y no cuenta los desparejos... que verifica ese if y cuando suma?